# Mantener footer abajo (no fixed, no absolute) con css

Tags: css

Cómo se puede mantener el `footer` abajo de la página siempre, pero sin usar fixed o absolute, porque se pueden dar varios casos:

En el caso de que el contenido no sea suficiente como para llenar la página, el footer no se queda abajo a no ser que le ponga un `position: fixed; bottom: 0` o `position: absolute; bottom: 0`

Pero si pongo una de esas dos, al ser el contenido más grande que la pantalla, el footer es visible siempre, en el caso de fixed hace scroll pero se queda siempre en pantalla, pero en el caso de poner absolute, al bajar se queda por el medio del contenido.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <header style="background:grey">Header</header>
    <div style="background:yellow">Contenido</div>
    <footer style="background:green">tiene que estar abajo pero no se queda abajo siempre...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Para temas de *layout* casi siempre *flexbox* es la solución. En este caso puedes poner el `body` como contenedor y que ocupe toda la altura y ponerle el valor `flex` en la propiedad `display`, también hay que hacer que se ordenen los elementos en vertical con  `flex-direction: column`; luego el contenido llevaría la propiedad `flex: 1` (que es equivalente a `flex: 1 1 0`)para que se expanda ocupando todo el espacio sobrante.

Uso el mismo HTML de tu ejemplo pero yo usaría un `div` que haga de contenedor para dejar el `body` limpio.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header style="background:grey">Header</header>
  <div style="background:yellow">Contenido</div>
  <footer style="background:green">tiene que estar abajo pero no se queda abajo siempre...</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Podrias escribir el codigo de la forma larga?